# UTF-8 Encoding name in downloaded file

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to let the user download the excel file with japanese name. It seems that it works IE 8 only and other IE and firefox, it is not working. Kindly suggest me how to hadndle this.

```
String fileName = dateString+"_マイページ情報.xls";
byte[] data = writer.getData();
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
response.setContentLength(data.length);
response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+URLEncoder.encode(fileName));
```

Answer (score 46):

I got it solved as the following.

```
fileName = dateString+"_マイページ情報.xls"; 
fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8"); 
try {
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        if(browserType.equals("IE")||browserType.equals("Chrome"))
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
        if(browserType.endsWith("Firefox"))
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"+fileName);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @zawhtut, what code do you use to get the browser type ?

Comment: request.getHeader("User-Agent");  I think. Its been a long time I posted this answer and now can't recall much.

Comment: This blog post is very helpful while solving this kind of issues http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/07/content-disposition-attachment-and-international-unicode-characters.aspx

and to know the browser details http://www.fromdev.com/2009/06/dealing-with-different-client-browsers.html

Comment: One of the most frequent reasons for this problem is white spaces between filename and file type specially in IE.

Comment: @rakeeee Thanks for the link. Based on that, I came up with a different solution, using a redirect. The best part is that it doesn't require any browser-specific code. See my answer below.

Comment: This is actually what Google Drive does, except instead of browser checking they just include both parameters i.e. it'd be something like "Content-Disposition": "attachment;  filename="fileName"; filename*=UTF-8''"+fileName);

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8"); fixed my issue.I had file name character problem and i tried all change encoding stufs but just have solved the code my problem.

Answer (score 11):

Use method [setCharacterEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29):

> Sets the character encoding (MIME charset) of the response being sent
>   to the client, for example, to UTF-8. If the character encoding has
>   already been set by setContentType(java.lang.String) or
>   setLocale(java.util.Locale), this method overrides it. Calling
>   setContentType(java.lang.String) with the String of text/html and
>   calling this method with the String of UTF-8 is equivalent with
>   calling setContentType with the String of text/html; charset=UTF-8.
>
> This method can be called repeatedly to change the character encoding.
>   This method has no effect if it is called after getWriter has been
>   called or after the response has been committed.

Modify your code with following:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This worked fine on Chrome. But did not work for me on Safari and Firefox. Both named the file according to the their URL-encoded "filename" attribute.

Comment: @yngwietiger: try using this for firefox-
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"+fileName);

Answer (score 5):

In the URLEncoder call, pass the second optional argument "UTF-8".
See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Given link is dead, instead use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did, and it works across **ALL** browsers that I tried (Chrome, Firefox and Safari). Also, I didn't have to write any browser-specific code.

According to this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/07/content-disposition-attachment-and-international-unicode-characters.aspx

> all browsers will attempt to derive the filename from the path
>   component of the URL

**So, if the browser requests a URL with the filename at the end, it will name the file correctly. This seems to be true for all browsers.**

In my personal case, the client doesn't know the filename that it wants to download. Our system does a GET for a file based on an ID. For example:

```
/api/file/download/<file_id>
```

So, what I did is to have that API look up the filename (we store it in the db, by file_id), URL-encode it, and **redirect** to a 2nd API that includes the filename. For example:

```
/api/file/download/<file_id>/<url-encoded filename>
```

Then, the 2nd API will use the file_id to find and stream back the contents of the file, and the browser will use the filename part to name the downloaded file.

NOTE: The 2nd API ignores the filename (doesn't need it). It also sets the Content-Disposition header to "attachment;" only (DO NOT set the filename. Let the browser get it from the URL.)

Comment: Sounds like you're in good shape, but as a note for other readers, be super careful about including user input (like the URL-encoded filename here) in file paths that you use on the server. This opens the door to path-traversal attacks. Instead, use an ID for files, and store the actual file name in a database; alternatively, establish a safe pattern for file names, and validate user input against that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

below works fine.

```
String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName );
```

Answer (score 0):

> No need to set setCharacterEncoding and all that just add below line
>   its works fine.

```
String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName );
```